# Is it possible to send an initial value?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a web method that returns a flux object when it will be time (it's linked to a pub/sub).
Would it at least be possible, only for the first call, to return a default?

```
public Flux<String> receiveStream() {
        return myReactiveService.getData() //here can I return a value at start? //.map(...);
```

Comment: Not sure I get your requirement right, but you might check this operator: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#startWith-T...-

Answer (score 2):

It is not that easy to do it "only for the first call". Each request is supposed to get its own sequence of Strings, unless you take specific steps to change that. And that is at two levels:
 - `WebFlux`: each request leads to a separate invocation of the controller method, so the `Flux` is newly instantiated
 - `Reactor`: most `Flux` are "cold", ie they don't generate data until they're subscribed to, and each subscription regenerates a separate dataset.

So even if you returned a cached `Flux`, it would *probably* still serve each request separately.

There is a way to `share()` a long-lived `Flux` so that later newcomers only see data that becomes available *after* they've subscribed to the shared `Flux`, which could help with the "only the first request" aspect of your requirement.

Assuming `getData()` by itself is cold (ie simply calling it doesn't trigger any meaningful processing):

```
AtomicReference<Flux<String>> sharedStream = new AtomicReference<>();

public Flux<String> receiveStream() {
    Flux<String> result = sharedStream.get();
    if (result == null) {
        Flux<String> coldVersionWithInit = myReactiveService
            .getData()
            .startWith(FIRST_VALUE)
            .map(...);
        Flux<String> hotVersion = coldVersionWithInit.share();
        if (sharedStream.compareAndSet(null, hotVersion))
            result = hotVersion;
        else
            result = sharedStream.get();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is [Flux#defaultIfEmpty](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#defaultIfEmpty-T-)